# How to launch python-mode on a buffer with vim?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vim, python-mode

I've just installed [python-mode](https://github.com/klen/python-mode) for my Vim, but I can't figure out how to run it on an open buffer, without saving the buffer as a `.py` file. Only way I can run python-mode seems to be by opening a `.py` file.

Comment: Try `:set filetype=python`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
:set filetype=python
```

This will tell Vim to treat the buffer as if it were a Python file.